# pass variable between methods in objective c: location manager and opencv

Tags: objective-c, opencv

Hi I am feeling so stupid to ask this question, I am hoping there is a very simple answer: I am trying to pass speed variable from CLLocationManager to opencv image processing and I am getting error.  I am thinking there must be an easy way to do that.  Can you please help me:

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
      didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
      CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
       double speed = loc.speed;
       //NSLog(@"%f", speed);
         }
  - (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image

{
  NSLog(@"%f", speed);
 }
```

Comment: How you are passing speed value to processImage method ?

Comment: That is where i need help how to pass the variable, I found if I just do

Comment: - (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image:speed, then I can not work with the image.  So can you please help me understand what is the correct way of passing the variable speed to the processimage method?

Comment: speed is double value here, but processImage need a different type. how you convert the speed value to required one?

Comment: actually all I want to do is to do this set of calculation to find speed within processimage method, but I am not sure how to do it, so please can you help me.   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
      didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
      CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
       double speed = loc.speed;
       //NSLog(@"%f", speed);
         }

Answer (score 0):

So essentially the issue is that your 'speed' variable is being declared as a 'local variable' meaning you can only use it within the locationManager method.

Perhaps you create an instance variable instead of a local variable so that it can be accessed by all of your methods in that class. Couple of ways to do this, one example - in your header file add:

double speed;

Then in your locationManager method, remove the term 'double'... (if you don't remove the term double then you will be creating a local variable which is not what we want). By using an instance variable, you will be updating the value of the variable declared in the header (.h file).

In your process image method, you should then be able to access the 'speed' instance variable and do what you need with it.